# Relative Cotangent Sequence

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $K\rightarrow S \xrightarrow{\varphi} T $ be maps of rings, and let $\Omega_{S/K}$ be the module of Kahler differentials of $S$ over $K$. Then we have:

> $T \otimes _S \Omega_{S/K}
>  \xrightarrow{\alpha}\Omega_{T/K}\xrightarrow{\beta}
>  \Omega_{T/S}\rightarrow 0$ is a right-exact sequence of $T$-modules.

I have a question about this sequence: Why is $T \otimes _S \Omega_{S/k}$ a $T$-module? My guess was: Since we have $T \otimes _S \Omega_{S/k}$ is an $S$-module, if the morphism $\varphi$ is bijective $T \otimes _S \Omega_{S/k}$ has a $T$-module structure with this definition: $t_1.(t\otimes_S ds)= \varphi^{-1}(t_1)(t\otimes_S ds)$. However, we don't have these conditions necessarily for $\varphi$.

Comment: The fact that $T$ is a factor of the tensor product gives you your $T$-action: you just act on the portion of the tensor that's in $T$.

Comment: @KReiser $\forall t_1,t \in T, ds \in \Omega_{S/K}:$ $t_1.(t\otimes_S ds) = t_1t \otimes_S ds$ is this obtainable from the definition of tensor product over $S$?

Comment: What do you mean, obtainable? You were after an action of $T$, you defined an action of $T$, everything should be okay, right?

Comment: @KReiser Yes, I thought it's not a new definition, by mistake. Thank you